# Chrome context menus do not render properly on primary screen when two screens are connected

Tags: fedora, chrome, multi-monitor, display-settings

I have a laptop with 4k display (3840x2400), and an external monitor with lower resolution (2560x1440).

When I have the 2nd screen attached, chrome renders the context menus incorrectly, but only on the laptop display (see A,D).  On the 2nd display, they are rendered OK (see C). If I remove the 2nd display, they are rendered OK on the primary display (see B).

[image: bad menu rendering]

Context menus in other applications, e.g. firefox, gnome files, all seem ok.

Software versions in use:

- Chromium 103.0.5060.114 Fedora Project
- Fedora 36, 5.18.19-200.fc36.x86_64
- gnome version 42.4

How can I configure chrome to understand both screen sizes correctly?

## EDIT - workaround found

*These routes sidestep the problem with a later version of chrome, rather than configuring the displays (or something else in gnome/wayland/fedora) correctly.*

1. using flatpak to install chromium-browser results in a more recent version than RPM.

Current version at time of writing: 105.0.5195.102

2. Far more disruptive workaround: swap fedora for ubuntu (22.04 LTS, also Gnome 42), this also yields a chromium version 105.x.y.z, possibly by flatpak. This is not a viable workaround for various reasons but helped with comparison at least.

I still don't know what configuration is incorrect that causes the problem, nor whether other applications will suffer similar problems. Hence just a workaround and not really a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Installing chrome / chromium-browser via flatpak, instead of the official fedora RPM, gives a later version.

This is possible in the Software gui using the dropdown menu on the top right to select between "Fedora Linux (RPM)" and "Flathub (Flatpak)", or via the command line as follows:

```
# install
flatpak install org.chromium.Chromium

# run - be sure we are executing the flatpak version 
flatpak run org.chromium.Chromium

# check version
flatpak list --app | grep chromium
> Chromium Web Browser  org.chromium.Chromium   105.0.5195.102  stable  system
```

Either there was a fix between version 103 and 105, or the RPM version that is tailored for fedora (*Chromium 103.0.5060.114 Fedora Project*) has differences that cause problems here.